# 'ball' object has no attribute 'top'

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a pong game but for some reason i am getting a error
'ball' object has no attribute 'top'

```
    ball1.x -= ball1.speed
    ball1.y += ball1.speed
    if ball1.top <= 0 or ball1.bottom >= 500:
        ball1.speed *= -1
    if ball1.left <= 0 or ball1.right >= 500:
        ball1.speed *= -1
```

the ball class

```
# this is the moving ball
class ball:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x =x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, self.rect.center,10)
ball1 = ball(290,200,20,20,white)
```

Comment: You didn't add the attribute top to your class.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the error message *means exactly what it says*?  You have attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`, and a `rect` made out of those, but no sign of a `top`.

Comment: how do I put on for top? do I just say self.top = top? or self.top = 500 my screen height

Comment: Have you assigned top though? I don't see a single mention in your ball object about ball.top. Maybe try looking for `ball1.rect.top`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add top, bottom, left and right to your class. Something like this:

```
class ball:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x =x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.top = self.y
        self.bottom = self.y + height
        self.left = self.x
        self.right = self.x + width

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, self.rect.center,10)
```